# Are structural engineers required to have liability insurance?

Tags: real-estate, property, homeownership, wisconsin

Are structural engineers required by law to have liability insurance in Wisconsin?

If it's *not* required, is it still common to have? Or do many structural engineers not carry it? (I know that's a little imprecise but I'm just asking for a generalization.)

Comment: There's multiple types of liability insurance. General liability insurance would protect the engineer for their acts, e.g. they crashed their work truck into somebody or they were on a site and hit somebody with a hammer. You're likely thinking _errors and omissions_ (E&O) or _professional indemnity_ which would protect them if they produced faulty plans and the building collapsed.

Comment: Okay, yeah. I was def thinking about E&O-type insurance. Just curious how common that actually is. But maybe there's no meaningful way to generalize that.